# Save emoji to text-file in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, emoji

I would like to save a text containing emojis to a html file using NodeJs.

However when I save the file and open it on web browser/ or text editor I see this wired character �.

How can I save the text with emojis to a text file, either as blank emojis or using UTF8?

This is my code,

```
fs.writeFile("./public/test.html", html, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you viewing the file with?  Not all apps can display all unicode characters.

Comment: @JimB. sublime text and safari :/

Comment: Have you tried textedit?  The default encoding for writeFile is utf8, which is unicode so supports emojis.

Comment: Feel free to point us to a sample of the file, too.